# Schwede-Shipley theorem for monoidal categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, ring-spectra

The Schwede-Shipley theorem gives a criterion for a presentable stable $\infty$-category to be the category of modules over an $\mathcal{E}_1$-algebra.  Is there any similar criterion for a monoidal presentable stable $\infty$-category to be the category of modules over an $\mathcal{E}_2$-algebra?

Comment: True iff the unit for the monoidal structure is a compact generator.

Comment: What theorem? They have more than one.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: I think based on context the OP must mean their paper "Stable Model Categories are Categories of Modules"

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks! So maybe abc.xyz could restate the question saying that he's considering the category of modules over an $E_1$(resp. $E_2$)-algebra *in the stable $\infty$-category of spectra*.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but just for completeness, the answer to this question is that yes there is a similar criterion (as Jacob Lurie comments above). This is Proposition 7.1.2.6 of Jacob's Higher Algebra. I'll post a screenshot here instead of transcribing the entire thing, as it's sort of long.

[image]